# how to get all member id for enmap when client.on?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js, enmap

I'm trying to get all the members id's, it work but it doens't work on enmap, sqlite just write one line with all the ids and its not what i want.

code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Started!');
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'dnd',
    activity: {
        name: ``, 
        type: "WATCHING"
    }
  });
  const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("951903386557636729");
  const Members = Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.id);

  client.profile.ensure(`${Members}`, {

    id: Members,})

  console.log(Members)


});
```

Comment: What is `client.profile.ensure`? Are you sure you want the first argument to be a string with comma-separated IDs? (e.g. `968526924589,839548354318,965413041202`)

Comment: Is your `ensure` this `ensure`? https://enmap.evie.dev/api/#enmapensurekey-defaultvalue-path--

Comment: it's from enmap to write on sqlite in the top of the code has client.profile = new Enmap({name:"profile"})

Answer (score 0):

i got with

```
const list = client.guilds.cache.get("951903386557636729");

list.members.cache.forEach(member => 
  client.profile.ensure(`${member.user.id}`, {
    id: member.user.id,
  }
```